# Validating and parse a string of key=value pairs using Java/Regex

Tags: java, regex

How to validate a string of key=value pairs using Java/Regex?

Sample Input:

```
key1=5&key2=8&key3=10
```

- pair - any number of pairs are allowed, separated by an ampersand, and constitute of `key=value`
- key - would be a typical variable name
- value - can only be an integer
- separator - pairs are separated by ampersand

A first attempt could look as follows:

```
String input = "key1=5&key2=8&key3=10"
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("([a-z]\\=\\d[&])");
```

The goal should be that

1. The syntax of the string can be validated
2. Key/Value pairs can be parsed out for further processing

Comment: is `"one=4&three=6"` valid?

Comment: Why a regular expression?  Why not just say `if s.equals("one=1&two=2");`?  (The point is that of course, you want to match other strings than just this one.  But unless you give us a hint as to _what_ strings you want to match, we can't help you.  We are not mind readers.)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want to validate a list of 'key=value' pairs separated by ampersand, a little how the query part of a URL would be built, then you can use following regex:

```
^(?:\w*=\d*(?:&|$))+$
```

or translated into a java regex:

```
String input = "one=1&two=2";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?:\\w*=\\d*(?:&|$))+$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.matches()) System.out.println("Matches!");
```

This is assuming that

- key is a sequence of word characters: `\w*`
- value is a sequence of digits: `\d*`
- key=value pairs end with an ampersand, unless it is the last pair: `(?:&|$)`
- There can be any number of pairs, but minimum 1

Above method is only useful to validate the string start-to-end, and is not suitable to extract the individual data portions. If you however want to extract each key/value pair, you need a little different approach. In that case you would use following regex:

```
(?:(\w*)=(\d*)(?=&|$))
```

or in a Java Program:

```
String input = "one=1&two=2";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:(\\w*)=(\\d*)(?=&|$))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println("key="+m.group(1));
  System.out.println("value="+m.group(2));
}
```

If there is truly a need to check whether key and value are equivalent in a way (`one` as a word vs `1` numeric), then that can be accomplished programmatically as you have the left and right of the `=` already parsed out.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(([^=&]+=[^=&]+)(&([^=&|]+=[^=&]+))*)+
```

Following are test cases

1. k=v         -> match
2. k=v&        -> doesnt match
3. k=v&k=v     -> match
4. k=v&k=v&    -> doesnt match
5. k=v&k=v&k=v -> match